# Способы получения информации о потоках процесса

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Допустим, есть какой-то процесс `var process = new Process()`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом можно получить информацию о потоках этого процесса, а именно:

1. Количество всех потоков
2. Количество worker threads
3. Количество IOCP threads

у Process есть свойство Threads `process.Threads`, но не понятно, что потом делать с этой коллекцией + интересует быстродействие этого (и других, если они будут) способов. Заранее спасибо.

**UPD:**
Возможно, есть способ получить `ThreadPool` другого процесса? Тогда методы `ThreadPool` решили бы все вопросы выше.

Comment: Что такое managed-поток? Если главный поток в .NET-программе вызывает нативную функцию, он в этот момент является каким потоком? Если нативный код создаёт нативный поток, и в нём вызывает управляемый коллбек, это какой поток?

Comment: @VladD эти подробности не так важны. Важно получить кол-во всех потоков (это просто process.Threads), вся загвоздка в том, как вычленить из них worker threads и iocp threads